# Check age of oldest file in directory ... But no other access

Tags: monitoring, healthcheck

There are roughly 30 users and 30 directories with this structure:

```
/home/user1/input/
/home/user2/input/
/home/user3/input/
/home/user4/input/
...
```

A check should monitor the directories.

If the oldest file in a directory is older than 5 hours, then the check should return 1 (WARNING).

The check does not run as superuser.

How to give the script the permission to check these directories and nothing else?

We use OpenSuse 42.1

There is a follow up question, how to solve this with SaltStack: [SaltStack: Change linux ACLs for /home/*/input/](https://serverfault.com/questions/879066/saltstack-change-linux-acls-for-home-input)

Comment: Sounds like a exam question.

Comment: @MatthewIfe yes, you are right. But it is not an exam. It is a real live question.

Comment: Your operating system is what? If non-standard facl is the solution, it might not be portable.

Comment: @JohnMahowald thank you for your interest. I checked the system Yes,  setfacl is available.